# Car gives off white smoke on inclines, struggles to accelerate for a moment

Tags: acceleration, smoke, clicking

I am driving a Hyundai Accent (08-11, I think it's 11). This car has had some Cylinder 1 misfires in the past (Reported by a FIXD device to read the codes). We had an oil leak that got fixed, and that check engine light error hasn't come back since.

The scenario occurs mostly when I am getting on the interstate on an inclined on ramp with a 270 degree turn. I assume the stress of uphill + turning agitates the issue. I have little to no issue ever driving up to 80mph, but once I am on a ramp, going anywhere from 25-40 mph and accelerating, I will hear a clicky noise from the engine, and the engine gets a little quieter. Following that, there will be smoke coming out behind me, only while accelerating. (looks white/light gray, hard to remember or focus while in motion) Typically I do my best not to push the car too aggressively when this occurs. After a good 5-15 seconds, the car will usually return to normal, and I can just accelerate like nothing happens. I also believe this issue does occur more frequently after longer trips, over 2 hours, even with stop inbetween.

I mention the cylinder thing because when that was more common, it seemed this issue would also occur on the interstate itself sometimes. I'd usually let my foot off the gas, and just lightly tap it until it wasn't clicking anymore, and caught on to the acceleration more readily. I believe we would change the coil packs(?) when we had the misfires. (sorry I'm not super mechanic literate)

I appreciate any advice/insight in advance. It's not something very easy to diagnose in the shop, since it requires either an incline or long runtime. I was hoping to maybe have some direction to point to, for a future visit to the shop

Comment: From what you have described, it sure sounds like you still have a misfire happening.

Comment: Have you checked the coolant and oil levels?  Are either of them dropping in level?

Comment: I know the oil levels haven't been dropping as much as it did, obviously due to fixing the oil leak. We do a monthly vehicle check and I haven't seen any of the fluids (power steering, coolant, transmission, brake, oil) drop in any significant amount over the last 1.5 years or so.